# Rails 5.2 API - Returning enum value in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, api, response

I currently have a postgres enum type setup in my user columns as `roles`. It works as intended like so.

Example:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  enum role: { admin: "Admin", viewer: "Viewer" } 
end
```

And the JSON response returns it as:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "role": "admin"
}
```

However, the `role` attribute is returning the key instead of the enum value. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try

```
def as_json(options = {})
  super.tap do |hash|
    hash['role'] = User::roles[role]
  end
end
```

Comment: This works for me as well. It's a shame that I have to essentially hack my way to get enums working for Rails. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this way. In `User` model file

```
def role_id
  User.roles[self.role]
end
```

and then you `role_id` method

Comment: Do you happen to know if there's another solution? I want to keep it so my JSON reflects the table that I have. In this case, I'd have to expose the method in `as_json`.

Comment: No, I'm sorry, it's the only way I found. If you find a better way let me know :)