# How to render enum as string not integer in mongoid (rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, enums, mongoid

I am using rails and mongoid gem. While using Enum in Mongoid model, with `extend Enumerize` things works. But upon rendering data as JSON to front-end (eg. using `ModelName.where(condition)`), the response for the enum field is not the string value of the enum but integer.

Example:

`enumerize :field_name, in: { abc: 0, def: 5, ghi: 10 }, predicates: true, scope: :shallow`

the rendered json looks like:

`{
    "model_name": {
        "field_name": 5 //instead of "def"
    }
}`

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try **ModelName.where(condition).as_json** before rendering.

Comment: thanks, but sadly didn't work

Answer (score 2):

This sounds similar to a question I answered a while back: 
[Rails 5.2 API - Returning enum value in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55185267/rails-5-2-api-returning-enum-value-in-json/55192508#55192508)

```
def as_json(options = {})
  super.tap do |hash|
    hash['field_name'] = ModelName::enum[field_name]
  end
end
```

Comment: After re-reading the problem, I don't thinks this is the correct answer. I would try suggestion by @code_aks

Comment: Thanks. WIll try that. I tried the similar code but earlier i placed similar code in mongoid config file. that didnt seem to work. But I will try placing this in model file.